# Retrieving a latitude/longitude in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using Leafletjs (http://leafletjs.com) to create a map in a web app and I can retrieve the latitude/longitude from clicking the map by doing:

```
var popup = L.popup();
function onMapClick(e) {
popup.setLatLng(e.latlng)
.setContent("You clicked the map at " + e.latlng.toString())
.openOn(mymap);
}
```

But I want to know if it's possible to also use Angular to display the lat/long by binding the data from the above JS too? I only know how to use basic Angular when data binding string literals, but not something like this.

Answer (score 0):

Everything is easy :) your `console.log` is located beyond collback borders,

```
function (position) {
  mysrclat = position.coords.latitude; 
  mysrclong = position.coords.longitude;
  console.log(mysrclat);
  console.log(mysrclong);
});
```

Comment: Thats good but not exactly what I was going for! I can get it to display in the console, which is still good, but I wanted it to render via angular in the view